# ESP8266 unable to read data from Google Firebase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, iot, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to make an IOT app. My android side is working good so far, however my ESP8266 is unable to read data from Firebase Database. There is no error while connecting to the internet using onboard ESP8266 though. Can anyone point to a possible error? Thank You

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#define WIFI_SSID "WiFi"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "xxxxxxxx"
#define FIREBASE_HOST "https://iot.firebaseio.com"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "xxxxxxxx"
int LED1 = D5;
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
  Serial.println('\n');
  wifiConnect();
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
  delay(10);
}
void loop()
{  
  if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    wifiConnect();
  }
  delay(10);
  Serial.print("Data from firebase:" + Firebase.getString("LED1") + "\n");
  digitalWrite(LED1, Firebase.getString("LED1").toInt());
  //digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
  delay(10);
}
void wifiConnect()
{
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);             // Connect to the network
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(WIFI_SSID); Serial.println(" ...");

  int teller = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {                                       // Wait for the Wi-Fi to connect
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(++teller); Serial.print(' ');
  }

  Serial.println('\n');
  Serial.println("Connection established!");  
  Serial.print("IP address:\t");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());         // Send the IP address of the ESP8266 to the computer
}
```

Comment: "my ESP8266 is unable to read data from Firebase Database" - what's the behavior? Any error messages?

Comment: @MarcelStör I'm sorry but there is no error message whatsoever. The code is compiling, uploaded successfully without any error. Even the execution of code is working perfectly. Only the issue is there is simple nothing returning from the database. My serial monitor shows "Data from firebase: ". Nothing is getting returned whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone encountering this issue. I got it working by removing the forward slash '/' at the end and the https:// from the start of Host Address.

Answer (score 0):

At the line:

```
#define FIREBASE_HOST "https://iot.firebaseio.com"
```

you should fix to:

```
#define FIREBASE_HOST "iot.firebaseio.com"
```